# Is there a Jewish tradition of God reviving Israel at Sinai?

Tags: sources-mekorot, agada-stories-legends, kabbalat-hatorah, resurrection-of-the-dead

I once heard that according to "Jewish tradition", though it could be mere hearsay, that there was a story or legend that when the Israelites saw God's presence upon Mt. Sinai (or heard His audible voice) that they all died and God had to revive them to continue speaking to them and give them the Torah, I assume since no one may see God and live (Exodus 33:20) or some similar reason. Is there anything in the Mishnah or Talmud (Gemara) that says anything remotely like this, or if not there then in later Jewish writings concerning that? I am trying to track down the source of this story.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Shemos Rabbah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exodus_Rabbah) (29:4) says:

> דבר אחר "אָנֹכִי ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ" רבי אחא ברבי חנינא פתח בו (תהלים נ, ז)
>   שמעה עמי ואדברה (כמ"ש בעשרת הדברות (פסיקתא רבתי, יב) עד) א"ר שמעון בן
>   יוחאי אמר להם הקדוש ברוך הוא לישראל אלוה אני על כל באי עולם אבל לא
>   יחדתי שמי אלא עליכם איני נקרא אלהי עובדי כוכבים ומזלות אלא אלהי ישראל
>   א"ר לוי שני דברים שאלו ישראל מלפני הקדוש ברוך הוא שיראו כבודו וישמעו
>   קולו והיו רואין את כבודו ושומעין את קולו שנאמר (דברים ה, כא) ותאמרו הן
>   הראנו ה' אלהינו את כבודו ואת גדלו וכתיב (שם) ואת קולו שמענו מתוך האש
>   ולא היה בהם כח לעמוד **שכיון שבאו לסיני ונגלה להם פרחה נשמתם על שדבר
>   עמהם שנאמר (שיר ה, ו) נפשי יצאה בדברו אבל התורה בקשה עליהם רחמים מלפני
>   הקדוש ברוך הוא** יש מלך משיא בתו והורג אנשי ביתו כל העולם כולו שמחים
>   ובניך מתים מיד חזרה נשמתן שנאמר (תהלים יט, ח) תורת ה' תמימה משיבת נפש
>   א"ר לוי וכי לא היה גלוי לפני המקום שאם הוא מראה כבודו לישראל ומשמיען
>   קולו שאינן יכולין לעמוד אלא צפה הקדוש ברוך הוא שהן עתידין לעשות עבודת
>   כוכבים שלא יהו אומרין אלו הראנו את כבודו ואת גדלו והשמיענו את קולו לא
>   היינו עושים עבודת כוכבים לכך נאמר שמעה עמי ואדברה:

The bolded part says that when they came to Sinai and God revealed himself to them, their souls flew away (i.e. they died) because God spoke to them but the Torah prayed to God for Him to revive them.

Comment: Thank you! Has the Shemos Rabbah been translated into English at all, like the Talmud has (examples for Babylonian Talmud: http://halakhah.com/tcontents.html -and- http://www.come-and-hear.com/talmud/index.html)?

Comment: Ah! Your answer enabled me to discover that this story's ultimate origin is in the Babylonian Talmud in tractate Shabbat 88a:

"With each and every utterance that issued forth from the mouth of G-d, the souls of Israel flew from their bodies, as it is written [Song of Songs 5:6], "My soul went out when He spoke." But since their souls departed at the first utterance, how could they receive the second one? G-d brought down the dew with which He will resurrect the dead and revived them."

See a slightly different translation here: http://www.come-and-hear.com/shabbath/shabbath_88.html

Comment: Can you add that quote from Shabbat 88a to your answer for the most accuracy?

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott Yes by Artscroll. It also had elucidation and footnotes, although I don't think it's available online. It's similar to their translation of the Talmud.